# Verascrypt Hidden Partition

Tags: encryption

I tried to encrypt the system  but it said that the partition for the hidden operation system must be at least 5% larger than the system partition veracrypt:bootencryption:getpartitionforhiddenos:865

but the partition with the current OS has a lot of files and using most of the disk, is it impossible to add a hidden volume, and if it is, then is normal encryption good enough?